# Installing Cairo and Winston for Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to install the Cairo and Winston packages fro Julia.

However, this is the following output that I receive when I try to test Winston.

`julia> Pkg.add("Winston")`
`INFO: Nothing to be done.`

`julia> using Winston`
`ERROR: could not open file /Users/sethhirsh/.julia/v0.2/Cairo/src/../deps/deps.jl`
 `in include at boot.jl:238`
 `in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:114`
 `in include at boot.jl:238`
 `in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:114`
 `in reload_path at loading.jl:140`
 `in _require at loading.jl:58`
 `in require at loading.jl:46`
 `vin include at boot.jl:238`
 `in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:114`
 `in reload_path at loading.jl:140`
 `in _require at loading.jl:58`
 `in require at loading.jl:46`
`at /Users/sethhirsh/.julia/v0.2/Cairo/src/Cairo.jl:3`
`at /Users/sethhirsh/.julia/v0.2/Winston/src/Winston.jl:3`

`julia> Pkg.add("Cairo")`
`INFO: Nothing to be done.`

================================[ ERROR: Cairo ]================================

`failed process: Process(`/Users/sethhirsh/.julia/v0.2/Cairo/deps/src/glib-2.34.3/configure --`prefix=/Users/sethhirsh/.julia/v0.2/Cairo/deps/usr`, ProcessExited(1)) [1]v
at /Users/sethhirsh/.julia/v0.2/Cairo/deps/build.jl:130`

================================================================================

================================[ BUILD ERRORS ]================================

WARNING: Homebrew and Cairo had build errors.

- packages with build errors remain installed in /Users/sethhirsh/.julia/v0.2
- build a package and all its dependencies with `Pkg.build(pkg)
- build a single package by running its `deps/build.jl` script

================================================================================ `

Any help in fixing these errors is appreciated.

Comment: You will probably have better luck on the issue tracker, this can be fairly open-ended.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like it has been fixed: https://github.com/JuliaLang/Cairo.jl/issues/71

Answer (score 0):

Me too got these errors once. For me When adding 'Winston' library 'Cairo' was a dependency. So What I would suggest is to completely uninstall Julia from system, because Package.rm() may not not make things clear for re-installation of packages alone. Then reinstall the Julia and make sure internet connection before typing Package.add("Winston"). Cairo will come along.